.Net 8 C# - Maui - Error compiling project - "is defined multiple times"
Has anyone come across this specific error? I've had this project working and deploying to an android device (ver 34 runtime) until this week.  I've added to new content pages and now when it compiles I'm getting the following error.
1>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: Error in obj\Debug\net8.0-android34.0\lp\139\jl\classes.jar:androidx/activity/ActivityViewModelLazyKt$viewModels$2.class:
1>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: Type androidx.activity.ActivityViewModelLazyKt$viewModels$2 is defined multiple times: obj\Debug\net8.0-android34.0\lp\139\jl\classes.jar:androidx/activity/ActivityViewModelLazyKt$viewModels$2.class, obj\Debug\net8.0-android34.0\lp\173\jl\classes.jar:androidx/activity/ActivityViewModelLazyKt$viewModels$2.class
1>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: Compilation failed

I've tried all the fixes I can find, including deleting the bin/obj folders.  Downgrading NuGet packages.  I can find similar issues on the web but nothing specific to this error.

You added two new content pages or added something to new content pages?


Go back to a commit before your changes. Try compilation. Works? -> 2. Add your changes one by one, always checking every step if it still compiles. 3. The one that breaks it should be the one you need to examine deeper. Heads up: There may be more than one.


all good points.  I've even tried re-installing VS2022 to make sure but you guys are probably right.  I'm worried that I'll add things back in and end up back at the same situtation.  I've searched this for days and no-one seems to have an answer to the problem.  It's obviously pulling in 2 jar files when it only needs one.

Well, something you did caused this. Even if it was upgrading a dependency. So first you need to track back to that very change that's the root cause (or contains the root cause). Sometimes, software development is like that. 2 Steps back to make one step ahead. But if you are in a dead end you can turn around and find the branch that leads you around or you can give up. What's it going to be?

Stern advice Fildor.  I know what development is like as I've done enough of it.  I just got stuck in this rut.  Thanks for the shake and I'll follow the usual logic to get out of this problem.  Thanks

four commits previous and now it builds.  Thanks again dragging me out from the pit of dispare 8-)   I will step by step rebuild to where I was and update this if/when I discover what caused the issue

This is the NuGet package references from my .csproj file.
When I upgrade just the BarcodeScanner.Mobile.Maui package that's when I start to get this error.
The next version of the Barcode package is 8.0.40.1 which is causing the issue.
Thought I'd post in case anyone else fell into the same trap.
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="BarcodeScanner.Mobile.Maui" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Maui.Audio" Version="3.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>

